# npm-debug module: how to enable and disable debug targets programatically?

Tags: node.js, npm-debug

In the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug#set-dynamically) for visionmedia's `debug` module for Node.js, I see that it is possible to enable and disable different debug targets programmatically.

My attempts to do this have not been very successful.

I created a barebones script: `test.js`

```
const debug = require("debug");
let test = debug("test"); // created before being enabled

console.log(1, debug.enabled("test"));

let namespaces = debug.enable("test");
// test = debug("test");
console.log(2, debug.enabled("test"));
console.log("enabled namespaces:", namespaces);

test("this is test");

namespaces = debug.disable();
// test = debug("test");
console.log(3, debug.enabled("test"));
console.log("disabled namespaces:", namespaces);

test("you shouldn't see this");
```

When I run the script using `node test.js`, I get the following output, which shows that `debug.enable("test")` has neither enabled the `test` debug target, nor has it returned any namespaces:

```
1 false
2 true
enabled namespaces: undefined
3 false
disabled namespaces: undefined
```

When I run the script using `DEBUG=test node test.js`, I get the following output, which shows that `debug.disable("test")` has neither disabled the `test` debug target, nor has it returned the names of any disabled namespaces:

```
1 true
2 true
enabled namespaces: undefined
  test this is test +0ms
3 false
disabled namespaces: undefined
  test you shouldn't see this +0ms
```

However, if I uncomment the lines that recreate the `test` debug target *after* using `.enable()` or `.disable()`, then everything works.

It seems that, in order to be able to enable and disable debug targets programatically, I need to use a different syntax:

```
debug("test")("message which can be enabled or disabled");
```

But it seems that this creates a new debug instance each time it is used, which would be wasteful. And it is not the standard syntax described in the documentation. And, even so, the `.enabled()` and `.disabled()` methods do not return a list of namespaces.

Is there something that I have badly misunderstood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused because I was relying a version of `debug` installed as a dependency for `express`. It turns out that the current version of `express` requires an outdated version of `debug`.

After running `npm install express` today (27 June 2021), the entry for `debug` in `package-lock.json` was as follows.

```
"debug": {
  "version": "2.6.9",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/debug/-/debug-2.6.9.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-bC7ElrdJaJnPbAP+1EotYvqZsb3ecl5wi6Bfi6BJTUcNowp6cvspg0jXznRTKDjm/E7AdgFBVeAPVMNcKGsHMA==",
  "requires": {
    "ms": "2.0.0"
  }
```

"version": **"2.6.9"**

(This is version "4.17.1" of `express`.)

This is because the `package.json` file for `express` explicitly calls for `"debug": "2.6.9"`.

Running `npm update` has no effect on this.

Running `npm install debug` does fix the problem. The entry for `debug` in `package-lock.json` gets set to the following:

```
"debug": {
  "version": "4.3.1",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/debug/-/debug-4.3.1.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-doEwdvm4PCeK4K3RQN2ZC2BYUBaxwLARCqZmMjtF8a51J2Rb0xpVloFRnCODwqjpwnAoao4pelN8l3RJdv3gRQ==",
  "requires": {
    "ms": "2.1.2"
  }
```

"version": **"4.3.1"**

Problem solved.